# Access and get values from multiple txt files in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a txt file organized in tables (lines and tabs) for each day of the year, i.e. 2013-01-01.txt, 2013-01-02.txt and so on.

I want to `VLOOKUP()` inside this files to get the product prices in column *Price*. My worksheet will look like this:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|   Price    | 2013-12-26 | 2013-12-27 | 2013-12-30 | 2013-12-31 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Watermelon | 1          | 1.5        | 1.35       | 1.85       |
| Botato     | 0.55       | 0.65       | 0.55       | 0.8        |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I can imagine two option for this:

1. Open which file using `Workbooks.Open()` get the values that I need then close file:

   ```
   Workbooks.Open (Path)
   'Get values
   Workbooks.Close
   ```
2. Open update files in

   ```
   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= ...)
       .name = path
   End With
   'Get values
   ActiveWorkbook.Connections(Path).Delete
   ```

Does someone think in another way to implement it? Which one is **faster** and better to understand?

Comment: No. The problem is that I already have the txt files. I don't think that import it in a data base will be easier than choose one of this options. :-)

Comment: And what about reading data from the text file directly without opening the text file in excel? You could use e.g. TextStream object, example here: http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/reading-txt-files-from-vba/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open each file in Excel and not using TextStream, then the following code should help you:

```
Sub OpenTxtFileInExcel()

Dim basicWorkbook, actWorkbook As Workbook
Dim basicSheet, actSheet As Worksheet
Dim filePath As String
Dim actDate As Date
Dim searchedProduct As String
Dim counterColumn, counterRow As Integer
Dim products As Variant
products = Array("Lemon", "Mango", "Durian")

Set basicWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set basicSheet = basicWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

actDate = CDate("01-01-2013")
counterColumn = 0

Do While actDate < CDate("01-01-2014")
    filePath = Format(actDate, "yyyy-MM-dd") & ".txt"
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=filePath, Origin:= _
        xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote _
        , ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:= _
        True, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:=False

    Set actWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set actSheet = basicWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    basicSheet.Range("B1").Offset(0, counterColumn).Value = Format(actDate, "yyyy-MM-dd")
    For counterRow = 0 To UBound(products)
        basicSheet.Range("A2").Offset(counterRow, 0).Value = products(counterRow)
        basicSheet.Range("B2").Offset(counterRow, counterColumn).Value = _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(products(counterRow), actSheet.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
    Next counterRow

    actWorkbook.Close

    counterColumn = counterColumn + 1
    actDate = DateAdd("d", 1, actDate)
Loop

End Sub
```

The command `Workbooks.OpenText` is very much dependend on the structure of your text files and you should record this command (in Excel 2007/2010: View > Macros > Record Macor ...), when opening the text file just via Excel in a way that the vlookup can work.

Comment: So you choose option (1) `Workbooks.Open()`. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: I think personally i would have chosen either (1) or (2) to achieve what you want but would have opened the text files with textstream in the background and run through all the data. But because you had already this idea with VLOOKUP, i just followed along and for this option (1) is the way to go.

Comment: The file is already in a table format, thats why I think that VLOOKUP is better then parse the file with a Regex or something.

Comment: Yes, makes also totally sense to me. I think sometimes coding is also about preferences or what you are used to :-)