# Importing multiple text files into the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to import one text file into Excel using below code.

```
Sub test()
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = "Time"
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 2) = "QueueName"
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 3) = "Count"
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\temp\Sample.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$2") _
        )**strong text**
        .Name = "Sample"
        .FieldNames = False
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

How do I alter it to import 4 different text files in a way that the files are imported into a single sheet with all the data aligned in following order

File 1 data
file 2 data
File 3 data
file 4 data

Means file 2 data should start where the file 1 data ends.
File 1 data may vary. So I do not know the starting range of the file 2 data.
What should be the `Destination:=Range("$A$2")`?

Comment: Correction the data of file 2 should start below the file 1 data

Comment: Correction the data of file 2 should start below the file 1 data

Comment: i added a sample below. change your `filefilter` to the `Textfile` you're loading. Also, the sequence of the file loaded is dependent on the sequence you select them. Better if you'll arrange the files by filename first then select them all. i haven't tested on many sample, i leave it to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access and get values from multiple txt files in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137636/access-and-get-values-from-multiple-txt-files-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetOpenFilename` excel property like this:

```
Sub Sample()

Dim myfiles
Dim i As Integer

myfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", MultiSelect:=True)

If Not IsEmpty(myfiles) Then
    For i = LBound(myfiles) To UBound(myfiles)
         With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;" & myfiles(i), Destination:=Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
            .Name = "Sample"
            .FieldNames = False
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    Next i
Else
    MsgBox "No File Selected"
End If

End Sub
```

Hope this works for you.